# PostgreSQL, Format Float

Tags: postgresql

I try to format numeric field

```
select to_char(12315.83453, 'FM999999999999D9999')
```

in this case all its OK. Result is **12315.8345**

But if value is between 0 and 1

```
select to_char(0.83453, 'FM999999999999D9999')
```

result is **.8345** without 0 (zero) but I need **0.8345**.

What kind of format should be indicate to `to_char` function to obtain result what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(0.83453, 'FM999999999990D9999');
```

I just changed the `9` before format `D` to `0`.